# Постобработка данных: фронтент или бэкэнд. За и Против

Tags: http, архитектура, frontend, backend, highload

По сети передаются данные, которые представляют собой полигоны  (для простоты можно считать, что это массивы `float`). В таком случае возникает вопрос, где лучше формировать окончательный вид этих данных в виде *json*: на сервере и передавать *json* или на фронте. Важное замечание. На фронте нужны именно *json*.

Кажется, что это лучше делать на фронте, чтобы не таскать по сети строки, а передавать массивы `float`. Но я не уверен в производительности JS. Насколько эффективно раскладывать всё по строкам?

---

Участники, которые собираются участвовать в конкурсе, обратите внимание, конкурс объявлен для того, чтобы люди поделились своим опытом решения подобного рода задач. Описание конкурса:

**В ходе беседы с участниками сообщества, выяснилось, что данная тема актуальна и может быть интересна. В связи с этим, хочется получить в качестве ответа максимально подробный ответ с описанием деталей задачи, которую Вы решали, а также принятое решение. **

**Я, в частности, подразумеваю, что речь идёт о High Load, т.е. о системах, которые обеспечивают безотказную работоспособность для не менее чем Q запросов и отвечают не более чем за указанный интервал времени T**

**Меня интересуют решения T == 1 sek. Q >= 50. Лучше, больше 100**

Comment: мы используем для передачи между сервером и клиентом protobuf, а geojson формируем в браузере уже

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Мы тоже на протобуфе сидим

Comment: посмотрите еще в сторону http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/

Comment: Опубликуйте типичные значения (числа!) **Q** (а также размер запроса-ответа) и **T** для сервера и клиентов (средние и экстремальные).

Comment: Вопрос из серии "где лучше менять состояние страницы - на клиенте или запрашивать новую верстку с сервера" - типичная палка о двух концах

Comment: @yolosora так я же с этим и не спорю. Хочу получить разные мнения. Вопрос именно про это

Comment: Поскольку клиенты разные (мощный десктоп vs дешёвый смарт) по производительности, ровно как и сети разные по пропускной способности, в каждом конкретном случае может выигрывать обработка на фронте или сервере. Поэтому в идеале ПО должно быть адаптивным: снимать метрики и производить оценку, какой способ обработки и передачи данных выбрать. Но это усложнит разработку, конечно.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin да, это называется мобильная версия.

Comment: Слегка дополнил ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вопрос, на самом деле, весьма сложный. Есть плюсы и минусы обоих решений.

1. Если делать всё на серваке, то все клиенты будут однородные данные получать и не будет дополнительно обработки. Следовательно, шанс, что на клиенте накосячат, меньше.
2. Лишняя нагрузка на сервак. Порой переложить дополнительную обработку на клиент - вполне валидное решение, чтоб снизить нагрузку.

Как пример, на текущем месте работы у нас используются карты. Необходима кластеризация точек. И проблема с тем, где это делать (на сервере или клиенте), стоит весьма остро. В базе миллионы пользователей, у каждого свои атрибуты (координаты, город, страна, пол и т.п). Нужно кластеризовать всё это дело с учётом атрибутов.

Раньше на серваке захардкожено было, что больше определённого числа юзеров не выдаётся.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Встал вопрос о кластеризации. Варианта два:

1. Сервер отдаёт кучу пользователей. А клиентские приложения сами кластеризуют как-то (iOS, Android и т.д. реализуют это на клиенте).
2. Кластеризовать на сервере. Клиентам только зум передавать.

Сервак, в принципе, неплохо масштабируется. Решили делать там. У нас бэк на ноде. Используем [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster), который подтягивает данные из базы и кластеризует всё. В риалтайме вполне справляется с этим делом. Для того, чтоб не проседало ничего, используем [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Из нашего проекта не могу скринов отсыпать, но выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. у нас всё API гоняется в json. Если у вас не слишком частые запросы, то лучше уж json использовать, оверхедом по размеру можно принебречь.

Comment: Было бы классно, если бы кто-нибудь рассказал про конкретные решения, которые были приняты в тех или иных ситуациях

Comment: Возможно, я даже сделаю этот вопрос конкурсным. Потому как он неоднозначный и есть огромное количество вариаций на тему ,которые важно обговорить

Comment: @hedgehogues добваил в ответ. Как пример, на текущем месте работы у нас используются карты. Необходима кластеризация точек на карте. И проблема с тем, где это делать (на сервере или клиенте), стоит весьма остро.

Comment: Я задавал этот вопрос ровно по той же причине, по которой указали Вы. Нам тоже нужно было кластеризовать точки на карте. Вопрос, где это делать

Comment: @hedgehogues мы пока решили делать это на сервере, т.к. иначе пришлось бы в каждом клиентском приложении это реализовывать (Android, iOS и т.п.), что по времени накладно.

Comment: В случае, если Вам нужна особая кластеризация. В противном случае, yandexMaps это умеет, кажется

Comment: @hedgehogues нам нужна особая; плюс, не только yandexMaps используем.

Comment: Тогда, конечно, это стоит делать на бэке. Если бы стартанул конкурс, расписали бы поподробнее, что за задача у вас? Почему нужна особая кластеризация и как вы это реализовали?

Comment: @hedgehogues в понедельник только смогу расписать. Можете стартануть )

Comment: В понедельник стартану. В выходные вряд ли люди этим заниматься будут

Comment: @hedgehogues нет особой разницы. Я на мете график приводил. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7950/15479 В целом, в любой день люди активны)

Comment: Насколько корректно будет, если я сейчас сниму галочку с правильного ответа, чтобы больше людей привлечь? А сразу после завершения конкурса её восстановлю?

Comment: @hedgehogues принимать или снимать галку с ответа - это решение автора. Вполне часто такое бывает, что принятый ответ меняется с появлением новых/более подробных ответов. Так что, думаю, вполне корректно.

Comment: @hedgehogues немного обновил ответ.

Comment: Если у Вас сервак на ноде, то это многое решает. И тут разница между бэком и фронтом уже менее замена

Comment: @hedgehogues у нас фронт не на js, если что. Клиентские приложения все нативные.

Comment: А почему тогда бэк на ноде?

Comment: @hedgehogues так исторически сложилось  ╮(︶▽︶)╭ Это решение было принято ещё до того, как я сюда устроился.

Comment: пускай клиент платит за лишнюю нагрузку на CPU, а не вы)

Comment: @SonicMyst клиенты могут по-разному реализовать кластеризацию, а потом ищи, у кого косяк =/

Comment: А вы не смотрели в сторону баз данных, которые поддерживают geospatial запросы? Вроде этой https://postgis.net, или она уже у вас в стеке?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ всё давно в MySQL. В другую базу это дело никто переносить на текущем этапе не будет =/

Comment: @Suvitruf у mysql тоже вроде какой-то geospatial index есть, честно скажу не работал с ним - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-spatial-indexes.html

Answer (score 6):

Лучше фронту всегда отдавать готовые, потребительские данные. Всю остальную логику с данными делать на сервере. Фронт у тебя должен быть "тупой". Получил данные и отобразил.

Лучше это в том числе потому что средний пользователь сегодня смотрит сайт не с десктопа, а с телефона. Часто это не топовый iPhone, а какой-то слабый и дешевый андроид. На нём всё медленно. Значит, чем меньше вы делаете ненужной работы на клиенте, тем быстрее работает сайт у пользователей, и тем более удовлетворены работой вашего сайта его гости. Это особенно важно если говорить не о сайтах уровня домашней страницы, а о настоящем Highload: потеря одного процента пользователей из-за того что ваш сайт недостаточно отзывчив может иметь очень ощутимые финансовые последствия.

Comment: да, да, расскажите это разработчикам google earth web например, или cesium

Comment: Как вопрос был поставлен, так я на него и ответил) Все зависит от проекта, задачи)

Comment: Всегда... эх, не стал бы я зарекаться так

Comment: Кластеризация на картах яндекса, как минимум, выполняется на фронте. Так что не обобщайте

Comment: Хочу заметить, что автор ничего не говорил ни про какой сайт в интернете

Answer (score 5):

Тут вопрос не до конца поставлен...

Я считаю что в этом случае решения по архитектуре нужно принимать исходя из количества передаваемых(обновляемых во времени) данных

Т.к. не понятно можно все сразу загрузить, сложить в Indexeddb и потом её кошмарить, что весьма простое решение.

Или же надо постоянно слать гео запросы на сервер, типа покажи мне что сейчас попало в такой-то bbox, т.к. фич терабайты или они меняются постоянно.

И еше не понятно, вы решаете задачу оптимизации, или просто пока рисуете на карте ?

Я по работе в основном имею дело с компьютерной графикой и гео-информационными системами.

Проекты ориентированы на realtime отображение на глобусе как ракета полетела, куда упали отделяющиеся части, какие измерительные средства какую траекторию померили и все в таком духе.

Сырых данных вагон и маленькая тележка, однако то, что прилетает непосредственно ко мне можно сказать песчинка. Бэкэнд у нас сложная штука- зоорпарк разного программного и аппаратного барахла, раскиданного по планете, передачей данных в системе является amqp брокер, и естественно он помимо моих данных обрабатывает еще кучу других потребителей и поставщиков сообщений. При таком распределении нагрузки - я сам восстанавливаю пакеты протобафа в geojson и тому подобные вещи на лету, ибо разным потребителям информация нужна все-равно в разном виде и гонять по сети/спутнику лишние байты тоже не хочется, еще нужно учесть что все это еще и дуплицируется по какой-то кучерявой логике детали которой мне неизвестны =)

Add: похоже, в вашем конкретном случае, с учётом указанных вами критериев, вы не можете полагаться на скорость клиентского девайса, соответственно, то и работу на нем лучше не выполнять.

Что касается кластеризации и геоданных - вы смотрели в сторону postgis? Это посгрес на стероидах, специально для geospatial данных и запросов

Comment: Так я конкурс для того и объявил, чтобы участники рассказали о тех проблемах, которые перед ними стояли. Прочитайте мои пожелания к ответу в описании конкурса: *В ходе беседы с участниками сообщества, выяснилось, что данная тема актуальна и может быть интересна. В связи с этим, хочется получить в качестве ответа максимально подробный ответ с описанием деталей задачи, которую Вы решали, а также принятое решение.*

Comment: @Дополнил ответ отсебятиной =)

Comment: У нас протобаф зашит в инфраструктуру. Т.е. у нас есть ребята, которые сделали фреймворк, генерующий по протофайлу go-сервис и структуры к нему

Comment: Того и надо. Отсебятины...

Answer (score 3):

Успешная практика разработки Unix говорит о том, что для связи компонент системы  **желательно** (всюду, где это не является невозможным по тем или иным причинам) использовать **текстовые** (с возможностью чтения и редактирования человеком) форматы представления данных.

Думаю, в вашем случае нужно гонять по сети **json** (т.е. *человекочитаемый текст*).

Comment: Вероятно, Вы занимались узкоспециализированными задачами. И никогда не имели дело с 1000 rps. Что уже говорить о 10000 rpc и всеми вытекающими. json здесь Вам сильно усложнит жизнь!!!

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что ответ стоит минусовать, но он явно затрагивает проблему лишь с одного, очень не широкого ракурса.

Comment: @hedgehogues, как известно, оптимизацией надо заниматься *после* соответствующих измерений, которые находят "бутылочное горлышко" в задаче. Вообще, при разработке крайне рекомендуется сначала создать *работоспособный прототип*, а затем последовательно выявляя проблемные места, улучшать его. Этакий итеративный процесс. (кстати, что именно вы называете `rps` (`rpc`)?) (и еще, по поводу скорости  передачи данных, неужели в вашей  задаче поток данных больше, чем скажем при показе HD видео?) (вы бы, кстати, поподробнее ТЗ на задачку выложили, чтобы систему в целом можно было оценить)

Comment: rps -- request per seconds. В нагруженных системах сразу возникает очевидность: для чего использовать json, когда он будет заведомо узким местом как по скорости передачи, так возможно и по объёму занимаемой памяти. Плюс, учитывайте время на сериализацию и десериализацию. Конечно, сейчас есть очень шустрые дамперы, но протобуф скорее всего будет быстрее. У него есть свои минусы, конечно. Но в текущем вопросе, мне кажется, они мало интересны. rps -- *requests per seconds*. RPC -- это другое remote procedure call (как раз история про protobuf). В моей задаче, система должна держать 1000 rps.

Comment: При этом, учитывайте, что данные хранятся в in-memory хранилище, на отдельной ноде (в частности, в  Redis). Я никогда не работал с HD видео и нагрузок там не знаю.

Comment: Для начала я бы померил на очень простых (тестовых) запросах, возвращающих минимум пользовательских данных, какой у вас может быть rps (конкретное число для текущей конфигурации сети, сервера и клиента). (кстати, просто интересно, один запрос в protobuf это  один RPC или можно упаковать вызов нескольких процедур в один сетевой запрос)

Comment: @hedgehogues я бы париться о канале и отдаче вообще особо не стал, ибо это +- легко масштабируется.

Comment: @hedgehogues стоит дописать ограничения в вопрос. потому что сейчас непонятно, что там на бэке, что на фронте, и какой объем. У меня, например, в приложении картина совпадает с той, что в вопросе (только не полигоны, а ноды в дереве), но 10 RPS, и объемы по 10-100 сущностей на запрос, редко - 10000к - и обычного json хватает.

Comment: @PashaPash давайте ограничимся системами high load. Определние дал

Comment: На сериализацию json уходит много времени. Мы пишем на golang. Использовали [json-iter](https://github.com/json-iterator/go). Протобуф шустрее. Скорее всего это происходит по двум причинам. Протобуф компактнее + протобуф быстрее декодирует. Json, возможно, полезнее на ранних стадия разработки. Но потом он обязан отмереть, если вы хотите скорости